# Border With Uniform BorderThickness Fails to Bind BorderBrush Color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (.NET Framework 4.0+):**

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace MCVBorderTest
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public string BorderColor { get { return "Red"; } }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MCVBorderTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Border BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BorderColor}" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MCVBorderTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MCVBorderTest.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MCVBorderTest">
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MCVBorderTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() }.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**Problem:**

Running the application will result in a window opening but the border has no color.  The Debug output has this message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=BorderColor; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=8990007); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Changing the BorderThickness to a non-uniform value, say 0,1,1,1, will result in the border receiving its expected color and no binding error in the Debug output.

**Question:**

Why does the BorderBrush's Color binding behave this way?

Comment: Why don't you bind to a `Color` property?

Comment: @mm8 For the purposes of this question, use of a System.Windows.Media.Color instance doesn't make a difference: the behavior still occurs.  From the perspective of my actual issue, this is a scaled down version of some existing code.  The ViewModel is in a separate project and used strings to avoid taking a dependency on PresentationCore.  I just happened to notice the binding error while testing and got curious about why it happens, especially when such a small change acts as a "workaround".

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a genuine bug to me, note the different behavior between the border brush and background:

```
<Border BorderThickness="10">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BorderColor}" />
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BorderColor}" />
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

An apparent workaround is to give your window a x:Name ("_this") and bind via the DataContext explicitly:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=DataContext.BorderColor}" />
```

Sadly, binding via RelativeSource also seems to exhibit this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and for providing a work around!  I can't accept it as the answer though because it doesn't answer my original question. :(